# How to change wifi passwords using the terminal

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, wifi, router

I have like most people a router in my home. Wifi is accessed using a password. Is it possible to change the Wifi password from the OSX terminal? If not, is it possible from Ubuntu's?

And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This totally depends on a router: different systems have different interfaces and store information like passwords differently.

For instance, dd-wrt stores password in nvram, so you can ssh to your router and do something like

`# nvram set wl0_wpa_psk="password123"`

So, just google router model and/or firmware + change password remotely.